# Is there an official Spanish Scrabble Dictionary?

Tags: scrabble

Last time I checked, there were some issues of contention with how the Spanish alphabet should be represented such as c+h vs ch, l vs ll, r vs rr and borrow letters such as k and w not used for Spanish words.  If I were to play with a Spanish tileset, which dictionary should I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a nice picture of a Spanish tileset that I found: h[ttp://gtoal.com/wordgames/details/spanish/](http://gtoal.com/wordgames/details/spanish/)

That page links through to the FISE webpages (Federacion Internacional de Scrabble en Espanol), where it is claimed that as of 2009:

> El diccionario oficial de Scrabble es la versión 1.0-2003 (edición
>   electrónica) del Diccionario de la lengua española de la Real Academia
>   Española (DRAE).

Hope that helps your investigations!

Comment: I have heard of the Real Academia before in my study of Spanish.  That is another interest topic for a linguistics forum, but nice to have some sort of definitive answer for a Scrabble Dictionary.  Now I can bust out my Spanish game at home and play some.

Comment: Actually I am really impressed with that link, I wish I could +2 you.  As an example on the Venezuelan site under using verb conjugations it refers to DRAE as the ultimate source in case of disagreements.  "Todos los tiempos y formas verbales, de acuerdo con el “APENDICE” de la ediciòn XXII del DRAE, y con los textos aceptados en el Art.37 de este reglamento. En caso de discrepancias, el DRAE prima sobre los textos auxiliares aceptados"